# Cannot Populate Javascript Object Properties with Values Using Function

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript object defined:

```
var APIUserItem = function () {
var 
    id = '',
    account_id = '',
    client_id = '',
    user_name = '',
    salutation = '',
    first_name = '',
    middle_name = '',
    last_name = '',
    organization_name = '',
    alternate_email = '',
    time_zone_id = '',
    utcoffset = '',
    date_created = new Date(),
    last_updated_date = new Date(),
    is_active = null,
    is_approved = null,
    classes = [],
    groups = [],
    permissions = [],
    properties = {},
    version_stamp_hash_string = '',

    getFromData = function (data) {
        id = data.ID;
        account_id = data.AccountID;
        client_id = data.ClientID;
        user_name = data.UserName;
        salutation = data.Salutation;
        first_name = data.FirstName;
        middle_name = data.MiddleName;
        last_name = data.LastName;
        organization_name = data.OrganizationName;
        alternate_email = data.AlternateEmail;
        time_zone_id = data.TimeZoneID;
        utcoffset = data.UTCOffset;
        date_created = data.DateCreated;
        last_updated_date = data.LastUpdatedDate;
        is_active = data.IsActive;
        is_approved = data.IsApproved;
        properties = data.Properties;
        version_stamp_hash_string = data.VersionStampHashString;

        // list of pointers to classes
        $.each(data.Classes, function (index, value) {
            class_pointer = new APIPointerItem();
            class_pointer.ID = value.ID;
            class_pointer.PublicID = value.PublicID;
            class_pointer.Name = value.Name;
            class_pointer.RelativeURI = value.RelativeURI;

            classes.push(class_pointer);
        });

        // list of pointers to Groups
        $.each(data.Groups, function (index, value) {
            group_pointer = new APIPointerItem();
            group_pointer.ID = value.ID;
            group_pointer.PublicID = value.PublicID;
            group_pointer.Name = value.Name;
            group_pointer.RelativeURI = value.RelativeURI;

            groups.push(group_pointer);
        });

        // list of permissions
        $.each(data.Permissions, function (index, value) {
            permission_pointer = new APIPermissionList();
            permission_pointer.ID = value.ID;
            permission_pointer.Description = value.Description;
            permission_pointer.Category = value.Category;
            permission_pointer.Level = value.Level;
            permission_pointer.ResourceType = value.ResourceType,
                        permission_pointer.Action = value.Action;

            permissions.push(permission_pointer);
    });

};

return {
    ID: id,
    AccountID: account_id,
    ClientID: client_id,
    UserName: user_name,
    Salutation: salutation,
    FirstName: first_name,
    MiddleName: middle_name,
    LastName: last_name,
    OrganizationName: organization_name,
    AlternateEmail: alternate_email,
    TimeZoneID: time_zone_id,
    UTCOffset: utcoffset,
    DateCreated: date_created,
    LastUpdatedDate: last_updated_date,
    IsActive: is_active,
    IsApproved: is_approved,
    Classes: classes,
    Groups: groups,
    Permissions: permissions,
    Properties: properties,
    VersionStampHashString: version_stamp_hash_string,
    GetFromData: getFromData
};
```

};

When I new up an APIUserItem by calling:

```
var user = new APIUserItem();
user.GetFromData(data);
```

then try to access the values in the new item like so:

```
document.write(user.ID);
```

all of the property values come back empty, except for the collections, which contain the expected data.  For example, I can loop through the Groups array from outside the object and access the properties of each group to display values.

The data object I passed to the GetFromData function call contains all the data - it just seems like the assignments to the local variables are not working?  I know I must have made some obvious mistake in my code.  Can anyone help me find my problem?

Comment: ahhh, my eye's why would you declare your vars like that???

Comment: @ryan Sorry if I broke your eyes :-)...See "The Revealing Module Pattern" here: http://blog.pluralsight.com/2012/10/02/revealing-module-pattern-structuring-javascript-code-part-iii/

Comment: Huh, thanks for the link, I hadn't seen that before. I think my instinctive reaction to not like that is because a variable in javascript can be declared without `var`, but then of course it ends up in global scope, and at a glance that's what it looks like is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assignments to the local variables are probably working, but they're just that: assignments to local variables. Your code does nothing to update the properties of the object. The fact that you create the object via that `return` statement that initializes properties from the local variables does not create a magic link between the local variables and the properties.

Your "getFromData" function should look something like this:

```
function getFromData( data ) {
  this.ID = data.ID;
  this.AccountID = data.AccountID;
  // and so on
}
```

The collection properties ("classes", "groups", "permissions") worked because they're objects, and you update their contents. That part's OK. Really, you don't need those local variables at all; you can just initialize the object properties directly.

Comment: Thanks.  So used to looking at other languages that my brain is fighting getting back into a Javascript frame of mind.